# Need to get working days of an employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to get Working days of an employees (exclude sat and sun) based on Year and Month parameter. If i select Year parameter then it should be from 2018/01/01 to today's date, how many days he worked. If i select Month parameter then for this month March how many working days.

Below is my query for Year Parameter

```
DECLARE 
    @MONTH NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @YEAR NVARCHAR(200) = NULL

SET @MONTH = NULL
SET @YEAR = 2018;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT E.EmployeeId AS ID,
            E.Name AS 'NAME',
            EL.EntitlementStart,
            EL.EntitlementEnd,
            EL.LeaveTypeId AS 'LEAVE TYPE',
            CASE 
                WHEN EL.EntitlementEnd < getdate()
                    THEN datediff(day, EL.EntitlementStart, EL.EntitlementEnd)
                        --WHEN @MONTH IS NULL OR @MONTH=''AND @YEAR IS NOT NULL AND @YEAR<>'' AND EL.EntitlementStart <= GETDATE() AND YEAR(EL.EntitlementStart)=@YEAR AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EL.EntitlementStart) != 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EL.EntitlementStart) != 7 THEN
                WHEN EL.EntitlementStart > getdate()
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE datediff(day, EL.EntitlementStart, getdate())
                END AS 'NumberofDays',
            (EL.EntitledAmount - EL.RemainingAmount) AS 'LEAVE TAKEN'
        FROM Entitlements EL
        INNER JOIN Employees E ON E.EmployeeId = EL.Employee_EmployeeId
        WHERE LeaveTypeId IN ('AL', 'MC', 'TRG')
    ) AS S
    PIVOT(SUM([LEAVE TAKEN]) FOR [LEAVE TYPE] IN (AL, MC, TRG)) AS pvt
)

SELECT *
INTO #TEMPSUMMARY
FROM CTE

--select * from #TEMPSUMMARY
IF (@MONTH IS NULL OR @MONTH = '') AND (@YEAR IS NOT NULL AND @YEAR <> '')
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM #TEMPSUMMARY A
    WHERE YEAR(A.EntitlementStart) = @YEAR AND A.EntitlementStart <= GETDATE() AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, A.EntitlementStart) != 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, A.EntitlementStart) != 7
END

IF (@MONTH IS NOT NULL AND @MONTH <> '') AND (@YEAR IS NULL OR @YEAR = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(A.EntitlementStart)
    FROM #TEMPSUMMARY A
    WHERE A.EntitlementStart BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, - GETDATE() + 1, GETDATE())
            AND GETDATE() AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, A.EntitlementStart) != 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, A.EntitlementStart) != 7
END
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to have a date table (including quick-to-access information about, say, whether it's a weekend - for example, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) and a public holiday table for queries like this.

Comment: ya,but currently don't have any table for weekends, only for public holiday we have table.I already have the query in where condition to exclude public holiday's

Comment: I'd recommend you also to start using proper data types (year and month seem to be a flag, but you're using nvarchar(100)) and definitely indent your code, that's really difficult to read

Comment: Sure James, Inside Stored Proc i will give proper data types.

Answer (score 0):

As far of my understanding we need to count the number of Working days in a current month if month is selected or in current year if year is selected accordingly till today. For this requirement you can follow the bellow code:

```
IF(ISNULL(@Month,0)=0 AND ISNULL(@Year,0)!=0)
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(Date_Col)
   FROM Table_Name
   WHERE YEAR(Date_Col)=@Year AND Date_Col <= GETDATE() AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date_Col) != 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date_Col) != 7
END

IF(ISNULL(@Year,0)=0 AND ISNULL(@Month)!=0)
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(Date_Col)
   FROM Table_Name
   WHERE Date_Col BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-GETADATE()+1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATEE() AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date_Col) != 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,Date_Col) != 7
```

Hope you had find your requirement.

Let me know if anything i got wrong.

Comment: Is the query satisfied your requirement?? or atleast gave any ides for your solution

Comment: I have edited the query(In my Post), but it still gives me the count without deducting sat and sun(Weekends), i guess my Number of days columns i should include some logic to filter out the sat and sun.

Comment: But the WHERE clause was perfectly alright to filter the Weekends, i hope we need to look after the CTE are you sure about the CTE what you had built?? if no please verify it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `CTE` to resolve this -

```
declare @YEAR bit = 0
declare @MONTH bit = 1
declare @StartDT datetime = (case when isnull(@YEAR,0) <> 0 then '2018-01-01' else dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0) end)

;with cte as
(
    select @StartDT as StartDT, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDT) as [WeekDay]
    union all
    select DATEADD(DD, 1, StartDT),DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DD, 1, StartDT))
    from cte
    where StartDT < getdate()-1
)
select count(distinct StartDT)
from cte
where [WeekDay] not in (1,7)
```

Change bit value of `@YEAR` and `@MONTH` to test this.